# Triggering event after preventDefault() doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="if-exist"]', function (e, options) {
    options = options || {};

    if (options.fileExist) {
        return true;
    }

    var target = e.currentTarget;
    var fileId = $(this).data('file');
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: Routing.generate('checkFile', {file: fileId }),
        type: 'HEAD',
        statusCode: {
            404: function () {
                alert('File does not exist');
            },
            200: function () {
                $(target).trigger('click', { 'fileExist': true });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

When clicking the button the HEAD request is send and when I've got 200 response than the click event is triggered again but this time with fileExist option. Listener is called again (I checked this) but nothing happens, it's like e.preventDefault() would still working. Any ideas?

## Solution

trigger() method will trigger jQuery event, but will not trigger default behaviour for a browser, which in my case is redirecting to another page. This code works:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="if-exist"]', function (e) {
    var target = this;
    var fileId = $(this).data('file');
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: Routing.generate('checkFile', { file: fileId }),
        type: 'HEAD',
        statusCode: {
            404: function () {
                alert('File does not exist');
            },
            200: function () {
                var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
                event.initEvent('click', false, false);
                target.dispatchEvent(event);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: instead of re-triggering the event, why don't you swap the anon function for a declared function and then just re-call that, potentially mitigating the issue with the preventDefault ?

Comment: I don't think I understand what do you mean here... After 200 response I just want a default behaviour for clicking the link. I've updated the snippet, maybe it will be more readable now - anonymous function is not doing anything if it's triggered with fileExist option.

Answer (score 0):

use e.stopImmediatePropagation(); to stop multiple calls of ajax.

Comment: Yeah, but it isn't what I wanted to achieve. I didn't have a problem with multiple ajax calls ;)