# Angular - Re-trigger event after event has been event.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng, asynchronous-javascript

I am using `Angular 12` with `PrimeNG` in my application to implement a `custom confirm()` function. The use case is the following:

When the user clicks on any checkbox or radio button on the form, before the event triggering, **a confirmation message should be shown, which asks whether the user actually wants to proceed or not**.

In order to implement this, I use `event.preventDefault();` in the first place to prevent the selection, then if the user clicks "Yes" on the custom confirm message, I want to **re-trigger** the **just prevented event**. Code example below:

**onCheckboxChange**

```
onCheckboxChange(event: Event) {
   event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default click in the first place

   this.openConfirmDialog( () => {
     // re-trigger event here, for example 'event.trigger();'
  }, event);
}
```

**openConfirmDialog**

```
openConfirmDialog(acceptAsync: any, event: Event) {
    this.confirmationService.confirm({
    message: 'Are you sure you want to make this change? Progress will be lost',
    accept: () => {
    //Actual logic to perform a confirmation
    acceptAsync();
   },
   reject: () => {
    event.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

}

Am I on the "right path" for this use case? I know I could specifically for each case set the value checked if it is a checkbox, for example:

```
this.event.currentTarget.checked = true;
```

or accordingly if it is a radio button, but I want to implement this in a "generic way", any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42455851/triggering-event-after-preventdefault-doesnt-work-as-expected), what I did was passing the target element that invoked the click event inside the `openConfirmDialog()` function, then on the `accept` event of the confirmationService, I re-click() manually the input element. For this functionality, we I needed to introduce a `boolean flag` ( `let fromManualClick = false` )

**Code Solution**

**onCheckBoxChange**

```
onCheckboxChange(event: Event) {
  if(fromManualClick){
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default click in the first place

    this.openConfirmDialog( () => {
    // my logic here
    }, (event.currentTarget as HTMLInputElement));
  }
  fromManualClick = false;
}
```

**openConfirmDialog**

```
openConfirmDialog(acceptAsync: any, srcElement: HTMLInputElement) {
  this.confirmationService.confirm({
  message: 'Are you sure you want to make this change?',
  accept: () => {
    acceptAsync();
    //re-trigger the click element
    fromManualClick = true;
    srcElement.click();
  },
  reject: () => {

  }
 });
}
```